# Why do I get JSON.parse error when using default code from "dotnet new react -o my-app"?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, reactjs, create-react-app

Running the terminal command 'dotnet new react -o my-app' builds a C# React app, but when testing the starting files it doesn't work.  Running 'npm start' from the my-app/ClientApp directory starts the app but navigating to the page http://localhost:3000/fetch-data you get the console error:

> "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data"

This is the block of code that it never gets past:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { forecasts: [], loading: true };

fetch('api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ forecasts: data, loading: false });
  });
}
```

It calls this controller, but the code in it never runs:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I NEVER GET CALLED");
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            DateFormatted = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index).ToString("d"),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        });
    }
```

I'm using these docs to build the app:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=netcore-cli

I plan to use this as a scaffold to build a new app, but I'm concerned that it isn't working before I've done any coding to it.  Does anyone know why or how to fix it?

Comment: _unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data_ - this usually means "it's not JSON".. what is the actual vaue returned?

Comment: Is the API actually running? Can you navigate to the API and get results? Also for the FETCH, can you fully qualify the path?

Comment: @stuartd it logs as undefined.

Comment: @flaZer  I forgot to include that part, 'dotnet build' works but running 'dotnet start' from the my-app directory always crashes dotnet with the error "dotnet quit unexpectedly" and sometimes I get "Exited with error code 134".

Navigating to the API route just loads the default homepage

Comment: As far as the FETCH, if by fully qualify the path make it "http://localhost:3000/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts", yes I tried that as well with no change.

Comment: Perhaps it goes without saying but, before you deal with the "consumer", you first have to deal with the "supplier" - most likely the JSON error occurs because there is no API to feed it JSON. As far as the FETCH, if you can't from a browser see the API results, then neither can REACT.  Also, Port 3000 is for the Web App - the API should have a different Port number (but to be sure, I'll build the test app that you are working from).

Comment: Anyway, I ran it using VISUAL STUDIO and all was well. I ran it using NODEJS (NPM RUN) and the FETCH didn't work... however I noted in the CMD WINDOW while running NODEJS, a few other URL... Not the Port 3000 URLs, but the 5001 Port URLs do work: https://localhost:5001/fetch-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because NODEJS (NPM START) isn't designed to host .NET, and the API call written in c#, is AspNet, AspNetCore, etc.  As an aside, NPM START kicks off resources located in the **package.json** file, and that file makes no reference to the Microsoft portion of the overall solution (yes the Microsoft article from which you are working is someone confusing since it doesn't directly point that out).

**IIS** (or in this case **Microsoft Internet Information Services Express**) can host both **React** and the API because the **Startup.cs** file and **AspNetCore** are configured to do so.

Real world, we typically generate our API's under one project, while building our UI application under another, each hosted on a unique Port, which at a minimum, offers a big plus by being able to test the **API / UI** independently (well, the API independently anyway - you can test the UI without the API as well but without API data, it's not always practical).

Comment: If it helps, or more importantly, is the answer, please mark it so. And if if it did help, I'm glad I was helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, the explanation is very helpful. I realize the problem was actually just that I couldn't get the API to start. 

I eventually just tried creating a new app in the same way and dotnet and npm run with no problems so everything is fine with the default code.  I'm guessing minor fluke happened with the initial installation.